# Change If InStr find exact matches only VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this line inside VBA which is looking for same values in Col82 (a list of words)

for example

```
Tea
Coffee
Tea & Cofee
AB Size
Size
Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism
Built In
```

At the moment it is not giving exact match in the output so Tea is recognised as separate to Tea & Coffee

this is what I have

```
If InStr(LCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt)), LCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Ecnt, 82))) Then
```

Thank You

Comment: @ chris neilsen wow thank you i was trying to figure out how to edit it when it told me you already did it - plz can you tell me how to show in the list you have done

Comment: Click the edited link by my name,  you'll see what I changed

Comment: As I remember InStr will not check for exact match, it is as it says in str(ing), why not use simple = instead?

Comment: thank you for the reply I am a new to VBA spent all day to figure this line please can you show in the line how to form correctly, and will it get exact matches even if words are like the ones in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I agree -- "why not use simple = instead?"
Maybe this code will help you explain your desires:

```
  Dim sCnt$, s82$
  sCnt = LCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt))
  s82 = LCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Ecnt, 82))
  
  If sCnt = s82 Then MsgBox "sCnt is equal to s82"
  If InStr(sCnt, s82) Then MsgBox "s82 is in sCnt"
  If InStr(s82, sCnt) Then MsgBox "sCnt is in s82"
```

EDIT: "share privately"?
From [Private SO Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275228/private-so-posts)
"Making certain questions 'private' would be the antithesis of [Stack Overflow's] philosophy."  So I think "no".

I suggest that you make simple examples that simply state your issue:

```
s1 = "this Machine has a Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism"
s2 = "Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism"
s3 = "This oven has Built In design"
' s1 & s2: "match"
' s1 & s3: "non-match" ??
' s2 & s3: "non-match" ??
```

I think your problem is not a programming problem, but a logic problem.

Comment: The cells in the search area i.e. Columns A - CC rows 2 - 35000 have other words apart from the words I need it to look for which are in Col CD (82) for example a cell would have this Machine has a Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism  so I need it to match Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism

But another Cell has This oven has Built In design    All matches found are copied to Sheet 2 with each Search word having its own column

I need the Built in and Built-In Pully-Lift Mechanism to be different columns - at the moment it is putting in either 1 or both the columns in Sheet 2 after running.